# What’s implied in ‘than usual’?

Tags: implication

For example, there’s sentence ‘I walked more than usual.’

Usual: that happens or is done most of the time or in most cases

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/usual

I thought ‘I walked more than I usually walked’ is correct because the predicate of the subordinate clause should be consistent with that of the main clause in the comparative sentence so ‘I walked more than usually’ is right. If I suppose it means ‘I walked more than it is usual,’ that means the fact is usual. How can the fact happen or be done? ‘Happen’ can be only applied to ‘event’ or ‘action.’ So my question is what’s implied in ‘than usual’?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247512/more-than-usual-vs-more-than-usually

I think there’s no definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP is quite right that "there’s no definite answer" here. Personally, I find I can live with either ***usual*** or ***usually*** in OP's exact cited context (with a fairly strong preference for the former), but [just like everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slept%20more%20than%20usual%2Cslept%20more%20than%20usually&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslept%20more%20than%20usual%3B%2Cc0), I'd never use the explicitly adverbial form in *I **slept** more than usual* (as that link shows, *...more than **usually*** is too rare to even show on the NGram usage chart).

It's worth noting that overall, both forms have [remained about equally common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20than%20usual%2Cmore%20than%20usually&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20than%20usual%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20than%20usually%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmore%20than%20usual%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20than%20usually%3B%2Cc0) in English for centuries...

[image]

---

It's also worth checking out the results from a "wildcard" NGram query asking which word occurs most often before *more than usual* and *more than usually*. Specifically, note that there are *no verbs at all* before the "flat adverb", but there are several *(**was, been, were, is, be, seemed, are**)* that commonly occur before the "explicitly" adverbial ***usually***.

[image]   [image]

---

So far as *interpretation* is concerned, if I were asked to distinguish two possible meanings for OP's specific example, I'd be inclined to say...

> *I walked more than **usual*** = *...more than **is usual** (for people in general)*
> *I walked more than **usually*** = *...more than **I usually walk***

...but that would only be if I *had* to specify a difference. If I was just presented with either version in isolation, I'd always assume the second interpretation - by default, ***usual[ly]*** is relative to the context-specific subject *(**me**)*, not the world at large.

Answer (score 0):

It describes a comparison to usual habits or the usual state of affairs.

"*I walked more than usual*" can be expanded to longer equivalent sentences:

- *I walked more than is usual for me*.
- *I walked more than it is usual for me to walk*.

The amount or duration of activity was higher than my usual activity of this kind. It's not the fact of walking that is usual here but the amount of walking which is signalled by the word "*more*".